# ¿Como puedo quitar eventos con off y resetear estos mismos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes amigos de stackoverflow, quisiera saber como puedo usar la funcion off para quitar unos eventos click ejemplo : `$("selector").off("click")` mi duda queda en como puedo revertir estos cambios porque no se usarlo con **on()**.

Gracias.

Comment: Si tal cual eso es lo que deseo.

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo : Removiendo evento click de todos los elementos

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

[Documentacion W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_off.asp)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").on("click", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p").off("click");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Click en este parrafo para cambiar de color.</p>
<p>Haga clic en el botón de abajo y luego haga clic en este párrafo (se elimina el evento click).</p>

<button>Remover evento click</button>
```

Comment: Esta muy bien la idea pero mi idea es que una vez que lo haya quitado me gustaría saber como retornar el evento al valor actual osea devolver el cambio.

Comment: No te entiendo. Creo que debes formular mejor tu pregunta te invito a ver el enlace sobre [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) así podríamos entender mejor lo que quieres hacer, como lo estas intentando hacer, que error esta recibiendo etc.